# Symfony2: Unable to find the controller for path "/en/login_check"

Tags: authentication, symfony

I am working on creating a login form in Symfony, following the example provided in the [Security chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html) of the Symfony book.

I have created the necessary configurations in security.yml, routing.yml and also implemented my ControllerAction and Twig template.

Here is what the security and routing files look like:-

**security.yml**

```
Firewalls:
    # defaut login area for standard users
    main:
        switch_user:        true
        context:            user
        pattern:            .*
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:             true
        anonymous:          true
```

**routing.yml**

```
login:
    pattern:   /{_locale}/login
    defaults:  { _controller: XYZSiteBundle:SiteUser:login }
login_check:
    pattern:   /{_locale}/login_check
```

As you can see, the `login_path` and `check_path` are both under the same firewall. 
I am still getting the following error:-

> Unable to find the controller for path "/en/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration setting is almost OK.Your problem is related to routing. You can solve this issue by just change your routing.yaml to

In routing.yaml

> login:
> pattern:   **/login**  defaults:  { _controller:XYZSiteBundle:SiteUser:login }
>
> login_check:
>
> pattern:   **/login_check**

because you \login and \logincheck pattern must match with security.yaml pattern. You need to remove /{_locale}/login and /{_locale}/login_check.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Asish, I had tried this, but it didn't work for me then. I have completely changed the routes now so won't be able to use this.

Answer (score 0):

The `check_path` value of your `form_login` section will not match `/en/login_check`.

You have to modify it to match `/.*/login_check`.

Comment: Thanks Florian. This is a valuable advice. 
Currently I am using /auth/login and /auth/login_check and it seems to be working fine. Will try the .* approach in the future though.

Comment: Or maybe a better regex :) it was an example. Something like /(en|de|fr)/login_check

Answer (score 0):

Your login_check route is missing controller default, should be:

```
login_check:
    pattern:   /{_locale}/login_check
    defaults:  { _controller: XYZSiteBundle:SiteUser:loginCheck }
```